# Interesting behaviour of type "decimal" in C# 

Tags: c#, decimal

If we declare padding as const decimal, the padding is not working.

mymoney = 1.2 and your money = 1.20, how can this behavior be explained?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        decimal balance = 1.2m;

        const decimal ConstPadding = 0.00m;

        decimal padding = 0.00m;
        decimal mymoney = decimal.Round(balance + ConstPadding, 2);
        decimal yourmoney =  decimal.Round(balance + padding, 2);

        Console.WriteLine(mymoney); // 1.2
        Console.WriteLine(yourmoney);  //1.20
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you define "is not working"?

Comment: mymoney = 1.2 and yourmoney = 1.20

Comment: Interesting note: compiled with the Mono compiler, the above program outputs "1.20" twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an accompaniment to Jon's answer, below is the IL produced from your code. As he mentioned, mymoney was never added.

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       61 (0x3d)
  .maxstack  6
  .locals init ([0] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal balance,
           [1] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal padding,
           [2] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal mymoney,
           [3] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal yourmoney)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.s   12
  IL_0003:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0004:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0005:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0006:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0007:  newobj     instance void [mscorlib]System.Decimal::.ctor(int32,
                                                                     int32,
                                                                     int32,
                                                                     bool,
                                                                     uint8)
  IL_000c:  stloc.0
  IL_000d:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_000e:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_000f:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0010:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0011:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_0012:  newobj     instance void [mscorlib]System.Decimal::.ctor(int32,
                                                                     int32,
                                                                     int32,
                                                                     bool,
                                                                     uint8)
  IL_0017:  stloc.1
  IL_0018:  ldloc.0
  IL_0019:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_001a:  call       valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal [mscorlib]System.Decimal::Round(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal,
                                                                                          int32)
  IL_001f:  stloc.2
  IL_0020:  ldloc.0
  IL_0021:  ldloc.1
  IL_0022:  call       valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal [mscorlib]System.Decimal::op_Addition(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal,
                                                                                                valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal)
  IL_0027:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_0028:  call       valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal [mscorlib]System.Decimal::Round(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal,
                                                                                          int32)
  IL_002d:  stloc.3
  IL_002e:  ldloc.2
  IL_002f:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal)
  IL_0034:  nop
  IL_0035:  ldloc.3
  IL_0036:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal)
  IL_003b:  nop
  IL_003c:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

To produce the IL (i.e. if you want to look under the hood in the future), just run ILDASM from a VS command prompt, then load your executable and double-click on the method that you would like to look at.

Comment: I am not really undderstand this IL codes, but really like to learn it. Do you have any book or article i can read? Thanks,

Comment: I'm not familiar with a resource to learn about MSIL (to me, the code is very similar to x86 asm which I picked up many years ago), but you can check out some of the links at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505820/what-are-some-resources-for-learning-msil).

Comment: @retide AH! No! This should _not_ be the answer, Jon Skeet's should. I only included this information to give the OP further information based upon what Jon said.

Answer (score 15):

The compiler "knows" that adding zero to a value "shouldn't" change the value - so it optimizes this out. Now arguably that's an invalid optimization given the nature of decimal addition, but if you look at the generated code, you'll find the computation of `mymoney` doesn't involve an addition.

I don't think I'd try to use adding 0.00m as a way to ensure a particular scale, to be honest. You *could* create your own code to enforce the scale, using [`decimal.GetBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits.aspx) and [the constructor performing the reverse operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1de0ya1.aspx) - but I don't think it would be terribly nice.

Do you definitely need this "two decimal places" form as an intermediate value, or is it only for presentation? If it's the latter, I'd look at format strings instead.

Comment: I'm interested in why the scale of the result is different when using the Constant as opposed to the normal decimal value.  It seems counter intuitive that the result would be different.  After all in both cases a decimal value is being added to the base value.

Comment: @Bueller: That's what the first bit of my answer is about - the compiler is removing the addition, as it knows it's only adding 0.

Comment: Thanks much, I wasn't thinking about optimization based on the pre-knowledge of the const value as opposed to the variable runtime value.

Answer (score 2):

```
balance + ConstPadding == balance
```

Because ConstPadding is zero!

You should -

```
Console.WriteLine(yourmoney.ToString("0.00"));  //1.20
```

Comment: but isn't that the same situation with padding?

Comment: This is an example, what happend if i need to return a decimal number not a string? Would you like to convert it back to decimal?

Comment: If you need to return a decimal number, why can't the code that displays it as a string worry about the number of decimal places?

Comment: When you have a decimal number 1.2 = 1.20 = 1.200 = ... (Like in math) The padding is display only, thus you have to specify the format that you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

The sum operation with the constant padding is getting completely excluded from the MSIL, yet it is there for a non-constant field.
I was not able to find any references to FCallAddSub function, unfortunately, but that's the one who "optimizes" the call.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken the complier isn't doing the addition with the constant decimal because it is zero.

Will post proof shortly.

Proof shown by Jon Skeet answer above.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen, if you seen Jon Skeets answer above he confirms that the compliler should optomize this out, and by the results we can say that this is fact.