# FCallAdd optimization

Tags: c#, .net, c++, clr

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497500/c-decimal-interesting-behavor/6497607) question brought a point of optimization of decimal summation operation. In Decimal type implementation, however, the whole summation operation is deferred to external function:

```
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
private static extern void FCallAdd(ref Decimal result, Decimal d1, Decimal d2);
```

Meaning that this method is implemented in CLR itself. Now ecall.cpp has a reference to

```
FCFuncElement("FCallAdd", COMDecimal::DoAdd)
```

Which invokes comdecimal.cpp function

```
STDAPI DecAddSub(LPDECIMAL pdecL, LPDECIMAL pdecR, LPDECIMAL pdecRes, char bSign)
```

**UPDATE**

Based on a comment below, the optimization occurs within compiler itself. I'm rephrasing the question thus. Could anyone point where can I get information regarding these optimizations?

Comment: Why? What is it you're trying to accomplish? Or is it just curiousity? :)

Comment: Just curiosity:) If CLR is so good optimize something, I'd like to know where, why and when.

Answer (score 1):

The optimization in the question which you link to wasn't performed inside this call, but rather it was done by the compiler. The compiler "knows" that adding 0.00m to a `decimal` doesn't do anything, so the IL it generated simply didn't include that `decimal` addition. In other words, `FCallAdd` was never called.

Comment: That's what I thought. So I'd rather look into the compiler code itself?

Comment: @Arthur looking "into the compiler code" is a little trickier, since there's no way MS will be releasing it any time soon. There may be a list of optimizations somewhere, though. And you can always try contacting Eric Lippert if you have specific questions. His blog is http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/